# What is the best way to schedule a view in database ( Clickhouse ) into a table, that updates the data at the specified time

Tags: python, automation, scheduling, clickhouse, prefect

Currently, the approach I take is,

1. clearing the rows in the table using python,
2. fetching the output of the view , in python and storing the result in a df
3. appending the data to the table using df.to_Sql in python.
4. Scheduling this script to be run every day at a specified time( prefect ).

I find this method, unappealing is because of the following reasons:

1. This method external , hence it involves latency.
2. This method is subject to various dependencies, like the sql connector that I am using for python, the scheduler like prefect, where debugging can get tricky If I have more than 10 tables..

Is there a better way/ package / tool to automate the process with least dependencies and latency ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Prefect 2 already? Regarding the load process, you may consider loading data to a temp table and merging from there -- by doing that in SQL, it might be faster and easier to troubleshoot. dbt is also a tool you can consider, and you can orchestrate dbt with prefect using the prefect-dbt package: https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect-dbt